# transform-origin property working differently on different text sizes

Tags: html, css

I am working on a webpage design. There I have to direct the text upright. I am doing it via transform rotate and setting the origin. However, the text on the side of each square positions differently specially on the right side. if the text characters are more or less the transform origin property works differently and the text on the side of the square goes to far or goes in. I have no idea what is going on. This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vag6z8z4/1/). I can't paste the code here that would be too messy and lengthy here.

```
.right-vertical-text{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 65px 85px;
  margin:15px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

the transform-origin here does not work consistently for all the side headers. 
for example the side header `header` is positioned very far from the square.

Comment: which is logic, because the width will be different if you have more text ...

Comment: If the code is too messy and too lengthy, then you should make a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should replace the css

```
.right-vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 65px 85px;
    margin: 15px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 135px; /*Added*/
}
```

For some reason the position of `h2` is depends upon the `width` of its parent